# JSONDecodeError in json.loads(request.body)

Tags: python, json, django, python-requests, http-post

I am getting JSONDecodeError in data=json.loads(request.body)

cart.js:

```
function updateUserOrder(productId, action) {
    console.log('User is authenticated')
    var url = '/update_item/'
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({'productId': productId, 'action': action})
    })
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('Data: ', data)
            location.reload()
        });
}
```

In views.py:

```
def updateItem(request):

data = json.loads(request.body)
productId = data['productId']
action = data['action']
print("Action:", action)
print("Product id", productId)
customer = request.user.customer
product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)

order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)

orderItem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(product=product, order=order)
if action == 'add':
    orderItem.quantity += 1
elif action == 'remove':
    orderItem.quantity -= 1
orderItem.save()
if orderItem.quantity <= 0:
    orderItem.delete()
return JsonResponse('Item was added', safe=False)
```

I am getting this error.
JSONDecodeError at /update_item/
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/update_item/
Django Version: 3.1.3
Exception Type: JSONDecodeError
Exception Value:
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Python version: Python 3.8.6
Django version: 3.1.3

I tried following other posts in stackoverflow and tried using cherrypy and various other ways for json.loads(request.body). Please resolve this error.

Edit:
Perhaps this may help:

Request information
USER
AnonymousUser

GET
No GET data

POST
No POST data

Comment: You are doing a POST but receive a GET in Django. This happens when a redirect is involved, often caused by a trailing or missing slash in the URL. Check your browsers debugger for details on the request(s).

Comment: I don't know why it's receiving a GET. How can I make it to POST..I tried checking errors, I could't find any.